# Consulta en mysql multiple select

Tags: mysql

Tengo problemas con esta consulta. La tabla `respuestassn` tiene registros de `si` y `no`. La tabla `ingreso` tiene varios registros de respuestas. Cuando quiero ver `SI` o `No` para cada registro en la tabla `ingreso`, no me devuelve datos.

```
SELECT r.nombre AS RiesgoBiolo, r.nombre AS riesgoPsicosocial
FROM ingreso i 
JOIN respuestassn r
WHERE i.id_ingreso=5 
AND i.riesgoBiologico=r.Id_respuestasSN 
AND i.riesgoPsicosocial=r.Id_respuestasSN
```

Comment: Lo que mostras no tiene nada pero nada de sentido... que son esos campos? como se conectan las tablas? que datos queres mostrar? que devuelve esta consutla?

Comment: puedes añadir las tablas implicadas y sus codigo

Comment: debes especificar la relacion que tienen las tablas con la clausula ON